# Как на jquery добавить добавить классы к родителю и ребенку, и удалить аналогичные классы у соседей?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть табы, при нажатии на которые добавлением классов меняется иконка вкладки. Нужно, чтобы при клике на любую другую вкладку у неактивных элементов удалялись модифицирующие классы.  Как правильно это сделать? [пример][1] для первых двух вкладок сделал, как оно примерно должно быть.

```
 [1]: https://codepen.io/Nick_Krogan/pen/zNQqam
```

Answer (score 1):

Следует пользоваться `toggleClass('модифицирующий класс')`, вместо `.removeClass` и `.addClass`. Это метод работает как переключатель, т.е если есть модифицирующий класс, то он его удаляет, если нет, то наоборот присваивает.

Comment: если использовать тогл, тогда клас будет включатся и выключатся при нажатии на один и тот же элемент. надо чтобы он удалялся только при нажатии на другие вкладки

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас есть некоторый набор элементов объединенных общим классом, например  `$('.vkladka')` или общим родителем `$('#vkladki > div')`, то очень просто удалить с них всех ненужный класс:

```
$('#vkladki > div').removeClass('active')
```

И после этого сразу назначить новый:

```
$(this).addClass('active')
```

А так-же можно исключить из группы элементов активный  с помощью [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('#vkladki > div').not(this).removeClass('active')
```

Еще вариант, получить соседние с нажатым элементы с помощью [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
```

**Живой пример:**

```js
$('#vkladki > div').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active')
  $('#vkladki > div').not(this).removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
#vkladki>div {  width: 100px;  padding: 4px;  border: 1px solid #ccc;  display: inline-block; cursor:pointer;}

#vkladki>div.active {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vkladki">
  <div class=active>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**Живой пример с `siblings()`:**

```js
$('#vkladki > div').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
#vkladki>div {  width: 100px;  padding: 4px;  border: 1px solid #ccc;  display: inline-block; cursor:pointer;}

#vkladki>div.active {
  border: 1px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vkladki">
  <div class=active>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: все классы active разные - в каждой вкладке иконка и бордер закрашиваются в свой цвет. если бы надо было применить одинаковый активный класс ко всем - вопросов бы не было. как можно выбрать все классы, заканчивающиеся на опред. слово?например, red_item, blue_item и т.п. перейдите по ссылке на кодпен внизу поста. там есть пример

Answer (score 0):

С помощью .find('Общий идентификатор табов') берешь все табы, и по клику на любой таб удаляешь у всех модифицирующий класс, затем добавляешь класс на кликнутый таб $(this).addClass('Модифицирующий класс');