# Боковая навигация по LandingPage как реализовать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-animation

Добрый день уважаемые. Разбираюсь с панелью навигации по одностраничнику возникли вопросы, очень надеюсь что вы подскажите как решить. Пример:

```js
window.onload=function(){
     var navigateMenu = $(".slider-nav-menu"),
          activeMenu = $(".menu-active");

     console.log($(".slider-nav-menu a").length + " = elem");

    navigateMenu.on("click", $("li"), function(){
      $(this).find("a").removeClass("menu-active");
            $(this).find("a").addClass("menu-active");
         
    });
}
```

```css
.block{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;  
}
#block1{
  background-color: #f00;
}
#block2{
  background-color: #0f0;
}
#block3{
  background-color: #0ff;
}
#block4{
  background-color: #f0f;
}
#block5{
  background-color: #ff0;
}
h1{
  margin: 25% 0 0 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slider-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.slider-nav-menu li:nth-child(even) a {
  background-color: black;
}
 .slider-nav-menu li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
 .slider-nav-menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 100% 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
 a.menu-active {
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transiton: transform 0.5s;
}
 a.menu-active:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="slider-nav">
        <ul class="slider-nav-menu">
            <li><a class="menu-active" href="#block1"></a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#block2"></a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#block3"></a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#block4"></a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#block5"></a></li>
        </ul>
 </nav>


<div id="block1" class="block"><h1>TEST1</h1></div>
<div id="block2" class="block"><h1>TEST2</h1></div>
<div id="block3" class="block"><h1>TEST3</h1></div>
<div id="block4" class="block"><h1>TEST4</h1></div>
<div id="block5" class="block"><h1>TEST5</h1></div>
```

1) Как присваивать класс menu-active только той ссылки на которую кликнул, удаляя перед этим данный класс со всех других?
2) Как реализовать добавление этого класса при прокрутке сайта? (Я прокрутил до 3 раздела у меня увеличился 3-й кружок, а со второго пропал), при этом размеры блоков в реальном проекте разные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Во-первых** у вас ошибка в `on()`

Вторым параметром передается селектор, а не jQuery-объект:

```
navigateMenu.on("click", "li", function() {
```

**Ответ на 1 вопрос**

> 1) Как присваивать класс menu-active только той ссылки на которую кликнул, удаляя перед этим данный класс со всех других?

На этот вопрос я отвечал тут:
[Как на jquery добавить добавить классы к родителю и ребенку, и удалить аналогичные классы у соседей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629515/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-jquery-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD/629535#629535)

В вашем случае сделаю так:

```
navigateMenu.find("a").removeClass("menu-active");
$(this).find("a").addClass("menu-active");
```

**Ответ на 2 вопрос**

> 2) Как реализовать добавление этого класса при прокрутке сайта?

Нужно обрабатывать событие `onScroll`.

Узнать текущую позицию скрола можно с помощью `$(window).scrollTop()`, а позицию объекта (раздела) относительно документа с помощью `.offset()`

**Рабочий код**

```js
var navigateMenu = $(".slider-nav-menu");

$(window).load(function() {

  console.log($(".slider-nav-menu a").length + " = elem");
  navigateMenu.on("click", "li", function() {

    navigateMenu.find("a").removeClass("menu-active");
    $(this).find("a").addClass("menu-active");

  });
})

$(window).scroll(function() {

  var scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop()

  $('.block').each(function(n) {
    if (scrolltop > $(this).offset().top && scrolltop < $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()) {
      navigateMenu.find("a").removeClass("menu-active");
      navigateMenu.find("a").eq(n).addClass("menu-active");

    }
  })

})
```

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#block1 {
  background-color: #f00;
}

#block2 {
  background-color: #0f0;
}

#block3 {
  background-color: #0ff;
}

#block4 {
  background-color: #f0f;
}

#block5 {
  background-color: #ff0;
}

h1 {
  margin: 25% 0 0 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slider-nav {
  position: fixed;
  right: 5%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.slider-nav-menu li:nth-child(even) a {
  background-color: black;
}

.slider-nav-menu li:nth-child(odd) a {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.slider-nav-menu a {
  display: block;
  margin: 100% 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

a.menu-active {
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transiton: transform 0.5s;
}

a.menu-active:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
  content: "";
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="slider-nav">
  <ul class="slider-nav-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="menu-active" href="#block1"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="" href="#block2"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="" href="#block3"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="" href="#block4"></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="" href="#block5"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<div id="block1" class="block">
  <h1>TEST1</h1>
</div>
<div id="block2" class="block">
  <h1>TEST2</h1>
</div>
<div id="block3" class="block">
  <h1>TEST3</h1>
</div>
<div id="block4" class="block">
  <h1>TEST4</h1>
</div>
<div id="block5" class="block">
  <h1>TEST5</h1>
</div>
```